# Why am i getting different results in the test case?

Tags: python, function, testing, case, words

I have a function that yields different results compared to what they are supposed to yield . This is for a scrabble game in python. Here's the method - the functions and their various types:

```
num = 0
length = (int(len(hand))/2) - 1
print('Current Hand: '),
print(displayHand(hand))

while (len(hand)>0):


    lettersGuessed = raw_input('Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: ')
    word= lettersGuessed

    if (isValidWord(word, hand, wordList)==False):
        print("Invalid word, please try again."+'\n')
    if (isValidWord(word, hand, wordList)==True):
        num += getWordScore(word, n)
        length -= 1
        updateHand(hand, word)
        print('"'+word+'"'+" earned " +str(getWordScore(word, n))+" points. "+" Total: "+str(num)+'\n')
        print('Current Hand: '),
        print(displayHand(hand))

    if (isValidWord(word, hand, wordList)==True):
        num += getWordScore(word, n)
        length -= 1
        updateHand(hand, word)
        print('"'+word+'"'+" earned " +str(getWordScore(word, n))+" points. "+" Total: "+str(num)+'\n')
        if length>=1: 
            print('Current Hand: '),
            print(displayHand(hand))
    if (isValidWord(word, hand, wordList)==True):
        num += getWordScore(word, n)
        length -= 1
        updateHand(hand, word)
        print('"'+word+'"'+" earned " +str(getWordScore(word, n))+" points. "+" Total: "+str(num)+'\n')

         #   print('Current Hand: '),
          #  print(displayHand(hand))
        if (length==0)&(isValidWord(word, hand, wordList)==False):
            print("Run out of letters. Total score: "+str(num))

    if (length==0):
        print("Run out of letters. Total score: "+str(num))
        break;
    if (length==0)&(isValidWord(word, hand, wordList)==True):
        print("Run out of letters. Total score: "+str(num))
        break;
    if (lettersGuessed =="."):
        print("Goodbye! Total score: "+str(num))
        break;
```

Here are the test cases that were done. Here's a test case that is supposed to result from the above output but it doesn't.

Can anyone please see what is wrong with my code?

Function Call:

```
wordList = loadWords()
playHand({'w':1, 's':1, 't':2, 'a':1, 'o':1, 'f':1}, wordList, 7)
Output:
  Current Hand:  a s t t w f o
  Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: tow
  "tow" earned 18 points. Total: 18 points

  Current Hand:  a s t f
  Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: tasf
  Invalid word, please try again.

  Current Hand:  a s t f
  Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: fast
  "fast" earned 28 points. Total: 46 points. 

  Run out of letters. Total score: 46 points.
```

Instead of it saying `Run out of letters. Total score: 46.` it says the following:

```
Current Hand: 
None
Run out of letters. Total score: 46
```

how do I remove the code:

```
Current Hand:
None
```

Can someone please copy my code and put in the letters in the hands for the various test cases please?

Comment: too much! Do you have an actual question?

Comment: yes I do.... can u please test my code and see why it doesn't come out the way that it is supposed to?

Comment: that's not a question. You should pick a single piece out of the code, a piece you don't understand, and ask a shorter question about only that. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: i edited it and fixed it up...can u check please?

Comment: no, but I'll give you a clue. In python, do you know what "None" represents?

Comment: it means that it's returning an empty string?

Comment: Almost, it means that it is literally "none". So if you step through your code line by line (use a debugger like the one in pycharm) you should see where the problem is. So when you say "how do I remove current Hand: None" you are actually printing the text "current hand" so if you want it removed, don't print it! etc etc

Comment: lol...i understand...but there are other complications as well beyond just that "none" part....can i email u and discuss it? i just added u to Google circles ...if u check u'll see it...

Comment: step through the code line by line in a debugger, watch all the variables change and that will provide the answer. If you still have not solved it by doing that, then perhaps.

Comment: i've gone through all of that and i'm stuck that's why i'm looking for help...i'm lost cause everytime i make changes through debugging i fix a problem but then a new problem shows up...its really confusing man...help!!!

Comment: if u can't help me out in python then i may have to quit this stupid course...how does one become good in python?

Comment: so i tried...but i still get the same results paul collingwood...can u help out please?

Comment: this is a good tutorial also; http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

Answer (score 0):

Q:

> how do I remove the code: Current Hand: None

A: In the third line, you print: `Current Hand:` regardless of if you have a hand or not. Make that code conditional (as you have elsewhere) on if your hand is `None` or not.

Or use:

```
if length>=1 and hand is not None: 
        print('Current Hand: '),
        print(displayHand(hand))
```